# How to to scroll smoothly between divs without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to scroll up and down a page with javascript smoothly. I have follow some code on [this page](http://www.xfunda.com/index.php?view=article&id=55%3Ajavascript-page-scroll-scroll-a-web-page-from-bottom-to-top-smoothly&option=com_content&Itemid=75)

But this only goes up, im quite confused on  how to get to specific div's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read this:** http://www.itnewb.com/v/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

This article will help you a lot with understanding how it should work!